# BJCP Study Material

Tags: bjcp

I'm going to begin studying for the BJCP exam.
I was looking into some study materials, and could use some direction.

I was thinking of Purchasing Michael Jacksons Beer Companion, the first edition is 80$ cheaper and I was wondering if it was essential I buy the 2nd revised edition.

More importantly, what references would you recommend and why?

Comment: I think this is potentially quite relevant and useful information for homebrewers, but there's no good "best" answer.   turning it into a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that the differences between revisions of Jackson's book would be worth worrying about (four years difference).  Don't forget about half.com, you can save a lot of money on books. I'm seeing $0.75 + shipping on the 1993 book.

Half of the exam material highlights the technical aspects of brewing, troubleshooting, and preventing process problems.  The other half focuses on style guidelines and tasting/judging beer. The technical, trouble-shooting, and process questions are more easy to prepare for; every possible question is given in advance in the study guide, so the exam is about as "open book" as a "closed book" exam can be.

The Exam Study Guide documents are [available here](http://www.bjcp.org/examcenter.php).  These study guide docs are packed with useful information for brewers of all levels, so even if you're not studying for the BJCP, it's worth a look.

Comment: I picked up my copy from a garage sale, paid a quarter.